# Row Cell selection and getting complete row data of the cell using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Have small requirement, I have to select multiple cells in a table. Once we click on submit button we have to show the respective row data of the each cell in alert message. I tried with below code, I'm getting cell data, but getting trouble to fetch row data of respective cell. Can any one help me pls, Here is the sample code.
Eg: Suppose I selected 2nd row 3rd column >> 3rd column should be selected and click on button I need to show alert "entire 2nd row data"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
         $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
        // alert(table.cell( this ).data());
    } );

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var rowdata = table.rows('.selected').data();
        var cellData = table.cells('.selected').data();
        //console.log(cellData);
        var consoleMsg = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < cellData.length; i++) {
            consoleMsg += cellData[i]+'\n';
            //consoleMsg += rowdata[i]+'\n';
        }
        alert(consoleMsg);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6vxgo1k/10/)

Comment: is works fine right? whats your problem?

Comment: Here my issue is...I need to get the complete row data insted of getting cell value. Like If I selected 2nd row 3rd column >> click on submit button >> I have show in alert entire 2nd row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
        var consoleMsg = '';
       $.each($('#example td.selected'), function(i,e){
            var allTd = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
        //console.log(allTd);

        $.each(allTd, function(x,y) {
            consoleMsg += $(this).text()+'\n';
        });

     });
     alert(consoleMsg);
    });
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b6vxgo1k/101/